# How to remove the commas from numeric string result?

Tags: java, string

I have `result`, which is either a text or numeric value, such as:

```
String result;
result = "avsds";
result = "123";
result = "345.45";
```

Sometimes the results also contain commas like:

```
result = "abc,def";
result = "1,234";
```

I want to remove the commas from `result` only if it is a numeric value, and not if it is simple text.

What is the best way of going about this?

Comment: Instead of removing comma, maybe you should replace them by another character, dot for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
    String regex = "(?<=[\\d])(,)(?=[\\d])";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    String str = "Your input";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    str = m.replaceAll("");
    System.out.println(str);
```

This only affects NUMBERS, not strings, as you asked.

Try adding that in your main method. Or try this one, it receives input:

```
       String regex = "(?<=[\\d])(,)(?=[\\d])";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        System.out.println("Value?: ");
            Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
            String str = scanIn.next();
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        str = m.replaceAll("");
        System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use two regexes. The first to make sure it is numeric (something along the lines of `[0-9.,]*`), and the second to clean it (`result.replaceAll("/,//")`)

Comment: Thanks Jim for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to parse the string first with any of the numeric classes (Integer, Double etc) after removing the unwanted characters, if the parsing succeeds, then it is a numeric and you can remove the unwanted characters from the original string.

Here I have used BigInteger since I am not sure about the precision for your requirement.

```
  public static String removeIfNumeric(final String s, final String toRemove) {
     final String result;
     if (isNumeric(s, toRemove)) {
         result = s.replaceAll(toRemove, "");
     } else {
         result = s;
     }
     return result;
  } 

  public static boolean isNumeric(final String s, final String toRemoveRegex) {
      try {
          new BigInteger(s.replaceAll(toRemoveRegex, ""));
          return true;
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          return false;
      }
  }
```